# Print json result from callback API in PHP

Tags: php

I'm consuming an API that whenever any order has a change it calls my url, and then I need to get the json result and treat it on my site, but I'm using $_POST["type"] and $_GET["type"] and it returns empty.

It's my first time consuming an API.

JSON responde in callback

```
{
  "type" : "ORDER",
  "content" : {
    "id":"10",
    "oi":"99999."
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you testing the POST? How about , sending the post to a webhook.site link and see how it is received... perhaps it is sent in the body, if so you need to use something like this to catch it as an array:   $webhookContent = '';

    $webhook = fopen("php://input" , "rb");
    while (!feof($webhook)) {
        $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
    }
    fclose($webhook);

    error_log($webhookContent);
    $webhookContent = str_replace("'", "", $webhookContent);

    $WebHookArray = json_decode($webhookContent,true);

Comment: Can you share a link to the source on which you’re basing your claim that the key/values of a JSON request body should be accessible in the `$_GET`/`$_POST` superglobals…?

Comment: `$_POST` and `$_GET` contain the parameters from your form to your PHP script, they have nothing to do with the API you're calling from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Catching a post with a php file is not the same as receiving $_POST from a form... most likely the data will be sent in raw so you catch the json... turn it to an array and then you can work it.

To catch the raw post:

```
$webhookContent = '';

$webhook = fopen("php://input" , "rb");
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);

error_log($webhookContent);
$webhookContent = str_replace("'", "", $webhookContent);

$WebHookArray = json_decode($webhookContent,true);
```

in this example the $WebHookArray will be the raw data sent. .. or the:

```
{
 "type" : "ORDER",
 "content" : {
  "id":"10",
  "oi":"99999."
 }
}
```